# Xalan IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, xalan, illegalaccessexception

I am using docx4j VariablePrepare as I am dealing with multiple runs. But while implementing it , I am getting following error. I have xalan 2.7.1 and serializer 2.7.0

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.apache.xml.serializer.ExtendedContentHandler from class org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createSerializationHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1233)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.createSerializationHandler(TransformerImpl.java:1060)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1268)
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1251)
at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.transform(XmlUtils.java:992)
at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.transform(XmlUtils.java:883)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.transform(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:239)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.filter(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:287)
at org.docx4j.model.datastorage.migration.VariablePrepare.prepare(VariablePrepare.java:80)
```

I am using following code for VariablePrepare.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage docxFile = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(inputFile));
mainDocumentPart = docxFile.getMainDocumentPart();
VariablePrepare.prepare(docxFile);
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. Serializer 2.7.1 worked for me.